# getting started with C++ and SQL Server

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++

What do I need to start with these languages?

I've been reading that the recommendation is first install `SQL Server 2008 R2`, then `Visual Studio 2010`. Does this already include C++ projects?

So after installing these, how would I start coding in C++ to connect to SQL Server?

Is this all I need?

Comment: Not clear why you think you need to install `Visual Basic 2010` to work with `C++`? Did you mean `Visual Studio 2010`

Comment: start by reading books, tutorials, questions on this site, searching the internet, ... the technologies you list are very popular, there is extensive documentation out there.

Comment: So Visual Basic is not needed? right?

Comment: Visual Basic is not needed if your are intending to write C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend [SQLApi++](http://www.sqlapi.com/).

Comment: This seems very interesting, so besides this `SQLApi++`, Do you recommend using also `SQL Server 2008 R2`?

Answer (score 1):

> then Visual Basic 2010, Do this already include C++ projects.

Ah - GUESS WHY Visual Basic 2010 is called VIsual Basic?

Exactly - it does NOT include anything EXCEPT visual basic. No C++.

You need a version of Visual Studio that includes C++ in order to use C++.