# Saving to a Database using C++

Tags: c++, sql-server

I am developing a C++ application and I have a problem when it comes to save ta a database.
I am using Visual Studio 2010 and the database that I am using is the Microsoft SQL Server Database.

Can please someone help to achieve this task since I am a beginner in C++?

Comment: Could you post the code that does reads from DB?

Comment: What exactly is your "problem"? If you don't give any details then it's difficult to help. And there are already [many questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22c%2B%2B%22+sql+server) on this site about C++ and SQL Server, including [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704245/getting-started-with-c-and-sql-server).

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with MS tools, you want to use the [SQL Server Native client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131291.aspx)